# How to write route in .net-core Razor Page without identifier?

Tags: c#, url, razor, .net-core, razor-pages

In `Razor`, I have 2 `Pages` :

- List (this page lists all the products)
- Product (this page gives detail for one product)

I cannot find the way to write the good route without the identifier List or Product. (I need it because the old website i need to update have this format for the URL)

- When the `Url` is http://www.example.com/category-of-products/ (with trailing slash at the end)

  - I need the List page to be displayed.
- When the `Url` is http://www.example.com/name-of-product (without trailing slash at then end)

  - I need the Product page to be displayed.

Now I am using :

```
@page "/{slug1}/{slug2?}/{slug3?}/"
```

in the List Page, but it is not make difference with and without slash.

Comment: You need to take some time to understand URLs and what they are and how they work. the backslash at the end can be used but it is only a visual for the user. you will need to have individual routes for individual requests. (technically you could use query strings or headers, but that would be bad practice)

Comment: your file explorer is a good sample for understanding `C:\Users` is the equivalent of `C:\Users\ `

Comment: Hi Kevin?. Thank you for your answer. So how to make the URL to work without any keyword for page such as "/list/category-of-product/ or /product/name-of-product/ but with the name of the category or the name of the product directly ?

Comment: I think the URL Rewriting in the .htaccess can make the difference for an URL with and without slash ?

Comment: I might misunderstand what you are trying to do, but why wouldn't you want an identifier for the route you use? a normal practice would be a get request with `/product/` to get all products (the last `/` does nothing) and to get a product with an id of one you would use the route `/product/1`

Comment: Yes, i don't want to have any identifiers for the route. For exemple here is my old website. http://www.anatum-objet-publicitaire.com/ecriture/stylo/bille/ is the url for the LIST and http://www.anatum-objet-publicitaire.com/stylo-bille-avec-embase-en-gomme is the URL for the product. I hope i am clear enought.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want this, maybe you can update your question and explain why? you need an Identifier to distinguish what resource to display otherwise there is no way to identify what to return

Comment: You are trying to create a bad fix for bad design. you need to handle your web routes correctly. if Http and Restful architecture dont work then look at GraphQL. get all and get one should have an identical routes with the only difference being get all will be `.../product` and get one will be `.../product/1` to get another resource `.../books` will get all books `.../books/10` will get a book with ID of ten. If you want certain books by an author you would call `.../books?author='Roy Fielding'`. You need to keep your routes consistent so they are easy to maintain and make logical sense

Comment: to get multiple resources you could use `../books?ids=1,5,10`

Comment: Hi Kevin, i can understand your point. I just find it is not a friendly url to make ../books?ids=1,5,1. For exemple Wordpress URL are friendly the same as what i need : https://editoile.fr/creer-gratuitement-un-blog-wordpress/. No identifier.

Comment: You really need to take time to understand how URLs work. your identifier is `creer-gratuitement-un-blog-wordpress. `on the wordpress showcase the routes are as follows `https://wordpress.org/showcase/` to `https://wordpress.org/showcase/tag-cloud/` to `https://wordpress.org/showcase/tag/cms/` if you use search you send a query string `https://wordpress.org/showcase/?s=blah` You can not navigate without specifiying a resource. in the last sample `showcase` is the resource

Comment: I can't help you because your question does not make sense. you need to set some time aside to understand how navigating with URLs works

Comment: Thank you. So wordpress is using URL rewriting, right ?